# Swiftmailer and PHP Variables

Tags: php, variables, swiftmailer

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
//*** Create the Transport ***
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.My-Hosting', 25)
->setUsername('MyUserName')
->setPassword('Password');
//*** Create the Mailer using your created Transport ***
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
//*** Create a message ***
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('NameOfInstance')
->setFrom(array('Support@test.com' => 'John Doe'))
->setTo(array("John@test.com" => "John Smith"))
->setBody('This is a test email message') ;
//*** Send the message ***
$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

How do I use a PHP variable (i.e. $email, $name, etc.) in the setFrom, setTo, and setBody arrays? (I do not want to type individual emails/names).

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understand your question and code (as it's unformatted), you should be able to simply replace the strings with the variable name of your choice.

For example, your original code, formatted, is:

```
setUsername('MyUserName') ->setPassword('Password'); 
//*** Create the Mailer using your created Transport *** 
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport); 
//*** Create a message *** 
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('NameOfInstance') ->setFrom(array('Support@test.com' => 'John Doe')) ->setTo(array("John@test.com" => "John Smith")) ->setBody('This is a test email message') ; 
//*** Send the message *** 
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Now, you can simply replace the "John@test.com" with $from_email or whatever variable name you choose ... and so forth with the other strings of text.

```
setUsername('MyUserName')->setPassword('Password'); 
//*** Create the Mailer using your created Transport *** 
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport); 
//*** Create a message *** 
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('NameOfInstance')->
    setFrom(array($from_email => $from_name))->
    setTo(array($to_email => $to_name))->setBody($body) ; 
//*** Send the message *** 
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```